# Should the Entity class implements interface?

Tags: java, entity, implementation

I have my Entity classes and I want to represent them with graphic. In my realisation, I have Drawable interface and classes which implement this interface for each Entity. As for me it is obviously that entities should implement Drawable interface, but I hear from experienced developers that this is a bad practice. I little bit confused because JavaDoc says:

> Entities may extend both entity and non-entity classes, and non-entity classes may extend entity classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very much opinion based (hence the close vote), but let's see if we can get some discussion going. Let's consider your proposition:

**I want my entity classes to implement an interface that has nothing to do with persistence**

Pros:

- Less duplication of class hierarchy. If something changes in the database, you might be able to have the program work as usual, or with only minor changes
- Flatter class hierarchy. You'll be able to visualize your data without a layer translating it to your `Drawable` objects

Cons:

- Entities are just data, and should not be responsible for drawing themselves. They should be transformed into domain objects first
- Passing entities into other layers of the system can cause bugs, when they're treated by code as domain objects